# How to input values into psvm parameter 'String args[]' in a main method?

Tags: java

I have the to classes VacationCostCalculator and a main:

```java
public class Program {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Not enough input arguments to run this program");
        } else {
            String transportMethod = args[0];
            String distance = args[1];
            VacationCostCalculator calculator = new VacationCostCalculator(Double.parseDouble(distance));
            double result = calculator.costOfVacation(transportMethod);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package com.itminds.vacationcost;

    public class VacationCostCalculator {
    
    private double distanceToDestination;

    public VacationCostCalculator(double distance) {
        distanceToDestination = distance;
    }

    public double costOfVacation(String transportMethod) {
        switch (transportMethod) {
            case "Car":
                return distanceToDestination * 1;
            case "Plane":
                return distanceToDestination * 2;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    public double getDistanceToDestination() {
        return distanceToDestination;
    }

    public void setDistanceToDestination(double distanceToDestination) {
        this.distanceToDestination = distanceToDestination;
    }
}
```

My task is to use the right design patterns to finish this application, but I have never learned what the values in the parameter in main is for.
I cant find a decent doc that exlplains it well. What do i have to do to make objects of the arguments bigger??? I dont even know what to ask for properly here..
How to run a sample test on this?? is it only through CMD terminal using Javac commands or can i test this by creating other classes that runs this????? i am currently using intellij

Comment: In main, you will receive a String[] which is an array of Strings.
For example, il will be `foo1, foo2`.
Here you expect to receive 2 parameters : at least : args.length < 2``.
You are parsing these strings to get the good type : `Double.parseDouble(distance)`

Comment: yes i understand that, but how to test this?? How to run a sample test on this?? is it only through CMD terminal using Javac commands or can i test this by creating other classes that runs this????? i am currently using intellij

Comment: To test this, either, you had the arguments into the IDE or you can test by typing them into the cmd space separated.
ex : `myprogram.exe foo1 foo2`
(I'm assuming it is a windows exe cause you spoke about cmd)

Comment: Edit your "Run configuration" that intellij created when you first ran your `main`. There you can add parameters.